# Can't decide between Task<IActionResult>, IActionResult and ActionResult<Thing>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

While I do understand the concept of `Task`, `ActionResult`, etc. I still feel unsure which would be most intuitive to type in a controller if nothing else is specified.

Taking consideration to be as explicit with a type returned, I should go like this:

```
[HttpGet] public ActionResult<Thing> Get()
{
  return Ok(Context.Things);
}
```

However, going for a generic type of API paradigm I should use this:

```
[HttpGet] public IActionResult Get()
{
  return Ok(Context.Things);
}
```

Finally, respecting the asynchronous nature of the API philosophy I should apply the following:

```
[HttpGet] public Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
  return Ok(Context.Things);
}
```

I can't decide between which is most appropriate in a general, green-field scenario. The first two work seemingly. Intuitively, I'd prefer to go with the third one but since it didn't work (the conversion isn't valid), I got worried that perhaps I'm barking up the wrong binary tree.

Not sure at all how to google it and I'm obtaining all kinds of examples. Uncertain how to judge which ones are of relevance, I prefer to ask.

Comment: Here is a good explanation for those options right from the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: @RacilHilan Great link. I missed that when I googled. Please repost your comment as an answer, adding some explanation, just a little. I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Here is a quick comparison of the different return options:

### Specific type

```
public Thing Get() {
    return Context.Things.GetThing(1234);
}
```

This is OK if the action will always return one possible type. However, most actions may return exceptions (i.e. status codes other than 200) that have different types.

### IActionResult type

This solves the problem above as the `IActionResult` return type covers different return types.

```
public IActionResult Get() {
    Thing thing = Context.Things.GetThing(1234);
    if (thing == null)
        return NotFound();
    else
        return Ok(thing);
}
```

For asynchronous action, use `Task<IActionResult>`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {
    Thing thing = await Context.Things.GetThing(1234);
    if (thing == null)
        return NotFound();
    else
        return Ok(thing);
}
```

### ActionResult type

ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduced the `ActionResult<T>` return type which offers the following benefits over the `IActionResult` type:

1- The action's expected return type is inferred from the `T` in `ActionResult<T>`. If you decorate your action with the `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute, you no longer need to explicitly specify its `Type` property. For example, you can simply use `[ProducesResponseType(200)]` instead of `[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Thing))]`.

2- `T` converts to `ObjectResult`, which means `return new ObjectResult(T);` is simplified to `return T;`.

```
public ActionResult<Thing> Get() {
    Thing thing = Context.Things.GetThing(1234);
    if (thing == null)
        return NotFound();
    else
        return thing;
}
```

For asynchronous action, use `Task<ActionResult<T>>`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Thing>> Get() {
    Thing thing = await Context.Things.GetThing(1234);
    if (thing == null)
        return NotFound();
    else
        return thing;
}
```

For more details, you can refer to the MSDN page [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Is the first one `public Thing Get() { return Ok(Context.Things);}` compilable? How can `Ok(Context.Things)` be converted to `Thing`? I cannot compile it.

Comment: @TheShortestMustacheTheorem I removed the `Ok()`, it was a copy/paste error. I also enhanced the examples with `.GetThing(1234)` to make them more realistic.

Comment: What is the difference between using `Task<ActionResult<Thing>>` and `Task<IActionResult<Thing>>` ? What is the recomended approach?

Comment: @variable `IActionResult` is an interface not a generic type, so `Task<IActionResult<Thing>>`  doesn't make sense. The async version would be `Task<IActionResult>`